# How is the field extension finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, transcendence-degree

I was reading the book *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves* by Silverman and I came across the below proposition

**Proposition**.Let C/K be a curve(Projective variety of dimension 1), and let t ∈ K(C) be a uniformizer at some nonsingular point P ∈ C(K). Then K(C) is a finite separable extension of K(t).

The proof says that K(C) is a finite extension of K(t) since the transcendence degree of K(C) is 1, but I don't see how it follows directly.Can some explain this?Here,K(C) is the function field of the curve C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$K(X)$ is a finitely generated extension of $K$ for any (irreducible) variety, because it's the quotient field of a finitely generated $K$-algebra, namely $\mathcal O_X(U)$ for some non-empty affine open.

Secondly, $t$ is not algebraic over $K$, because $\mathcal O_{C,P}$ is a discrete valuation ring containing $K$: If $t$ was algebraic, then one could conclude that it is invertible in $\mathcal O_{C,P}$, which a uniformizer in a DVR never is.

So in your situation $K(C)/K(t)$ is also finitely generated. Because $K(C)$ and $K(t)$ both have transcendence degree $1$ over $K$ the extension $K(C)/K(t)$ must be algebraic (transcendence degrees add up in tower of extensions). Finally, finitely generated + algebraic implies finite.

Comment: "If t was algebraic, then one could conclude that it is invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{C,P}$",can you tell me how does this follow

Comment: @user631874 take $f=a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+\ldots+a_nX^n$ the minimal polymial of $t$ (assuming it exists). then $a_0 \neq 0$, because $f$ is irreducible. But then we can write $f(t)=0$ as $t^{-1}=-\frac{1}{a_0}(a_1+a_2t+\ldots+a_nt^{n-1})$. The RHS is contained in $\mathcal O_{C,P}$, because it contains $K$ and $t$.

Comment: Ah I see,got it!Thanks a lot.